# Temporary disabling exposed ports on Docker

Tags: networking, docker, ports

I would like to temporary disable some docker container ports at runitme, so without changing the image or stopping/starting the container.

I have some services running, a webclient, an authentication service a mongodb instance and also a loadbalancer, all of them in the same VM.

Since there is no API to modify exposed ports at runtime in docker, I have to work with iptables command.

So I've built some code which disable the ports related to a particular container name passed as parameter.

I have the following rule for the authentication server:

```
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.16/32 ! -i br-3ec61cf14e6e -o br-3ec61cf14e6e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 -j ACCEPT
```

Which my code modify as the following:

```
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.16/32 ! -i br-3ec61cf14e6e -o br-3ec61cf14e6e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 -j DROP
```

At this point I am expecting I can't authenticate anymore, but I can still do it.

At the same time if try the same code against the load balancer, everything works fine, I can't access the URL as expected.

These the original rules for nginx:

```
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.11/32 ! -i br-3ec61cf14e6e -o br-3ec61cf14e6e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 81 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.11/32 ! -i br-3ec61cf14e6e -o br-3ec61cf14e6e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.11/32 ! -i br-3ec61cf14e6e -o br-3ec61cf14e6e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Here the modified ones:

```
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.11/32 ! -i br-3ec61cf14e6e -o br-3ec61cf14e6e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 81 -j DROP
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.11/32 ! -i br-3ec61cf14e6e -o br-3ec61cf14e6e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.11/32 ! -i br-3ec61cf14e6e -o br-3ec61cf14e6e -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```

Below the output of docker ps command

```
[root@sandbox-test-28 ~]# docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                               NAMES
d007479faaf4        service-auth-nodejs         "/bin/sh -c \"/usr/bin"   2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp                                              authentication-microservice
c073989b49ce        nginx                       "/bin/bash -c /etc/ng"    2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10000->81/tcp   nginx-microservice
432ea895d90a        web                         "/bin/sh -c \"/usr/bin"   2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp                                              webclient-microservice
0c8141da8c0b        mongo                       "/entrypoint.sh mongo"    2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                                            mongo-microservice
[root@sandbox-test-28 ~]#
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The subnets in your rules are different:

```
172.18.0.11/32 (authentication service)
```

vs

```
172.18.0.16/32 (nginx)
```

So presumably, the packets for your authentication server arrive via `172.18.0.16` and are still allowed by a different rule.

Comment: Subnet is the same, the IP is different 172.18.0.16 for authentication and 172.18.0.11 for nginx
Those in the question are all the rules for both services, 3 rules for load balancer and one for authentication.